# Building counters from paginated search results...?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm creating eBay style search panes that allow users to narrow their results set by certain criteria. For example:

> **Tags**
>
> Literature (8)
>   Fiction (4) 
>   English (4)
>   American (3)
>   Non-fiction (2)

The number of results which have that property is in brackets. Initially, I built the counters by putting this code in my display results loop:

```
if(isset($tags[$row['tags']])) {
    $tags[$row['tags']]++;
} else {
$tags[$row['tags']] = 1;
}
```

Then I paginated my results and that stopped working - the query only returns enough data for the page you are on, so the counters only represent the results on that page.

Can anyone suggest another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to run a second query for `tag, COUNT(*) in <table> GROUP BY tag` to get total numbers for each tag.

**edit:**

[Check this out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).  This is a new one by me, but it looks like what you want.

Start your query with `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, then follow up your query with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

Comment: Tags are just one of several criteria. If at all possible I would prefer to avoid additional queries.

Comment: Your other option is to do a full query, without a limit.  Then you can count up your tags and do pagination logic in PHP.  This will be a heavier approach, at least in the PHP if not on the database, but it should be more flexible.

Comment: You're right, but it's a tough call - extra queries versus grabbing the whole data set on every page. I wonder how other sites that display this kind of information structure their code.

Comment: I know what you mean.  This has to be a common problem.  The `FOUND_ROWS()` thing is really helpful, but I didn't see anything about how to pair it with a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE tagid=$tagid
```

This would require another query however. Please supply more info about your pagination methods.

Comment: I paginate with LIMIT:

    $from = (($page * $results_per_page) - $results_per_page);
    $sql .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$results_per_page;